# Creating an empty RubyMine project

Tags: ruby, automation

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CNXZ.png)  Some time ago I used to do a bit of web automation using Ruby and RubyMine. I used to use the command **testgen project project-name --pageobject-driver=watir** to create an empty project in Rubymine (which included hooks.rb etc). Now, I'm just getting an error. Any thoughts on creating an empty project in RubyMine? I know you can use **cucumber --init** but you don't get all the subsidiary files... Thank you!

Comment: You mean File -> New Project isn't going to work for you?

Comment: Hi, yes. Sorry, I should have been clearer. It's about creating the project framework with all associated file structure i.e. features (dir), support (dir), hooks.rb, etc, etc...